# Is it possible to get the image src from previous page and display it in new page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way to display an image that was clicked on a previous page to a new page?
For example if I have `step-2.php` make a user pick an image and when clicked it goes to `step-3.php` and display it there.
I hope I explained myself. Please Any help is appreciated.

This is the code from step-2

```
<a href="../business_cards/step-3.php">
<img src="../img/5.jpg" alt="Image1">
</a>
```

I want that click to sent the img src to step-3 if possible.
This is what I have in step-3

```
<img src="../img/5.jpg" alt="imageCanvas">
```

**EDIT** Trying to do the $_SESSION method

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["imageid"] = "image url";
?>
<a href="step-3.php?imageid=../img/5.jpg">
<img src="../img/5.jpg" alt="Image1">
</a>
```

Comment: Only if you have access to the other page and pass the image as parameter

Comment: Possibly by setting a cookie with js when you click on the image, and then checking for the cookie in the next page

Comment: Would I do that on a separate js file? or can I do it within step-2.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your image URL in a session like this for clean URLs:

```
session_start(); // At the top of your header file
$_SESSION["imageid"] = "image url";

// Next page:
$imageurl = $_SESSION["imageid"]; // This in the next page
echo "<img src='$imageurl' />";
```

Or pass it on with a query string like this:

```
Header("Location: https://www.website.com/page.php?imageid=imageurl");
// Or
<a href="https://www.website.com/page.php?imageid=imageurl">Next page</a>

// Next page:
$imageurl = $_GET["imageid"]; // This in the next page
echo "<img src='$imageurl' />";
```

If you want a clean URL and you want to use it on multiple places use the `$_SESSION` method, else just use the `$_GET` method, choose wisely...

Comment: So this is not possible to do from localhost?

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, but I get the same results as the other answers. I updated my question to how I am using your code.

Comment: Nevermind now it works. My error on your code was that I didn't change the `imageurl` part to the actual image url. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea on how to do the $_SESSION method could you help me?

Comment: @AndresRivera If it works then you don't have to do anything with sessions

Comment: What if I want to clean up the url? so the path to the image won't appear there? could it be done?

Comment: @AndresRivera Check my answer, I have added the session part for clean URLs

Answer (score 2):

step2 link to step 3 with the imgsrc being in the query string.

```
// encode the query string first
<a href="../business_cards/step-3.php?imgsrc=<?=urlencode('../img/5.jpg')?>">
```

step3 relays the get data into an html element

```
// query string is automatically decoded with GET or POST methods 
<img src="<?=$_GET['imgsrc']?>" alt="imageCanvas">
```

Comment: can't get this to work. It does sent me to step-3.php but it doesn't show the image there.

Comment: in your html code for step-3.php did you change the img to `<img src="<?=$_GET['imgsrc']?>" alt="imageCanvas">`

Comment: what is the full url of step-3.php when you get there

Comment: Yes I did and I get `http://localhost/fyiprints.com/business_cards/step-3.php?imgsrc=..%2Fimg%2F5.jpg`

Comment: It does the same thing just the url changes. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. To get the GET method to work do I have to wrap my code in a form?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add a _get variable to your link, in the href add something like

```
href="code.php?image=<?php echo $image_src?>"
```

on the following page the image can be found in

```
$_GET['image']
```

Comment: but how would I add the src of the image? hmm I'm not that good in php that's why I'm asking if you don't mind.

Comment: @AndresRivera my solution does it for you

Comment: you would assign it to the $image_src variable.

Comment: I did but the image does not appear in step-3.php